# UIScrollView can not scroll after add subview to superview

Tags: uiscrollview, ios6, storyboard

My viewController already have main scrollView for show content as subview in Storyboard. After that i'm try to add new subview for show image gallery (UIScrollView) that also work fine. then when i'm close image gallery view, the main scrollView content size decrease down to fit of the viewController bounds. How can i avoid that situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure that some method of UIScrollViewDelegate the parameter scrollView refers to mainScrollView and you are resizing the contentSize?

Comment: I used the mainScrollView like property. i'm pretty sure it connected with UIScrollViewDelegate. For resizing, i'm not resize contentSize. but i'm print log of contentSize after add gallery view. it seem like auto resizeContent via storyboard constraint.